# Transfering attached documents in Access to a Word Template

Tags: vba, ms-access

I currently have a form in MSAccesss that gets users to attach any relevant documents and a script that runs an automation of populating data from Access into a Word Template.

The code that I have is not being flagged down as a bug or has any compiling errors, however, the attachment does not seem to be appearing on the generated word document.

```
Set appWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then 'create a new instance of word if not opened
    Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If

Dim doc As Word.Document
Set doc = Documents.Add(CurrentProject.Path & "\BCPPrototype_Template.dotm")

Dim rsa As DAO.Recordset
Set rsa = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("heh_attachment")


If rsa.RecordCount > 0 Then
    doc.Bookmarks("call_tree").Range.InsertFile (CurrentProject.Path & "\" & rsa!FileName)
End If

Set doc = Nothing
rsa.close
set rsa = nothing

end sub
```

Edit:

Implementing what was suggested below, current code is

```
Dim rsa As DAO.Recordset2, fd As DAO.Field2
Set rsa = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT AttachmentFieldName FROM TableName")
Set fd = rsa("AttachmentFieldName")
fd("FileData").SaveToFile CurrentProject.Path
If rsa.RecordCount > 0 Then
    doc.Bookmarks("call_tree").Range.InsertFile (CurrentProject.Path & "\" & rsa!FileName)
end if
```

but the file simply isn't appearing. I tried to comment the code to save the file and manually save it in the same folder too, same issue of file attachment not appearing occurs. I also tried without the bookmark and simply referring to the cell range, same issue occurs.

ideally, what I am trying to accomplish is that, by inserting the file attachment in generated word document. I can access the file from the generated word document by clicking on it.

Comment: If file is stored in an Attachment field, it must first be saved out to folder location then inserted to Word document from the folder.

Comment: @June7 so if i'm understanding you right, the thought process would be to extract the string of the file name (which is already done), save it to a folder (probably current project path) then only call it out using this automation code?

Comment: Not the string of the filename, the file object itself - FileData. Research SaveToFile method. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/Concepts/Data-Access-Objects/work-with-attachments-in-dao

Comment: @June7 ok, i think i get the thought process. let me try it out and thanks

Comment: rsa!FileName does not have the file path of the extracted file. Code is still pointing to the attachment field, not the extracted file. What type of file? Need to test for empty recordset before extracting file. Don't use RecordCount for that, use `If Not rsa.EOF Then`.

Comment: @June7 it is a .docx file. I thought after saving the file, using ```currentproject.path & "\" & rsa!filename``` would be able to refer to the filepath as a string? The filename is a field from a query I used to extract the filedata, filename and filetype

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245922/discussion-between-june7-and-scoosch).

Answer (score 0):

If file is stored in an Attachment field, it must first be saved out to folder location.

```
Dim rsa As DAO.Recordset2, fd As DAO.Field2
Set rsa = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT AttachmentFieldName FROM TableName")
Set fd = rsa("AttachmentFieldName")
fd("FileData").SaveToFile CurrentProject.Path
```

Follow with code to insert file into Word document. Options for insertion are:

1. contents of a file (doc, docx, txt) can be inserted as more content in the Word document
   `doc.Range.InsertFile "file path/name here"`
2. embed an image file (jpg, bmp, tif, wim, png)
   `doc.InlineShapes.AddPicture "file path/name here"`
3. file can be embedded in an object frame that either displays content or an icon and double-click opens the original file from folder location
   `doc.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject , "file path/name here"`
4. a hyperlink string that opens the original file from folder location
   `doc.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Range, Address:="file path/name here`

Comment: The code works, but the attachment does not seem to appear on the document. It is rather odd, originally the bookmark is in the centre of the cell, however, after automating, the bookmark moves to the left. The code seems to work, but the attachment simply doesn't appear

Comment: Edit your question with code you're now using and what debug steps you've taken

Comment: @dbmitch will follow up on that